# Can't play audio from an online link, using Amazing Audio Engine

Tags: ios, audio, audio-streaming, the-amazing-audio-engine

I am trying this code to achieve online streaming/buffering with the help of amazing audio engine, but it throws me following error:

> AEAudioFilePlayer.m:148: AudioFileOpenURL: 'wht?' (2003334207)

Here is the code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.audioController = [[AEAudioController alloc] initWithAudioDescription:[AEAudioController nonInterleaved16BitStereoAudioDescription] inputEnabled:YES];
    _audioController.preferredBufferDuration = 0.005;
    [_audioController start:NULL];

    [self initWithAudioController:self.audioController];

    AEAudioFilePlayer *oneshot = [AEAudioFilePlayer audioFilePlayerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlOfSong] error:NULL];

    _oneshot.removeUponFinish = YES;
    [_audioController addChannels:[NSArray arrayWithObject:oneshot]];


    }

    - (id)initWithAudioController:(AEAudioController*)audioController {

        self.audioController = audioController;
        NSError *error = NULL;
        BOOL result = [self.audioController start:&error];
        if ( !result ) {
            // Report error
            NSLog(@"The Amazing Audio Engine didn't start!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"The Amazing Audio Engine started perfectly!");
        }

        return self;
    }
```

Comment: is it on iOS 9? Do you have that [done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32331282/3151066) ?

Comment: yes arbitrary loads are allowed to yes, and it does work on iOS 9

Answer (score 0):

in .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AEAudioFilePlayer *player;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AEAudioController *audioController;
```

in .m file

```
-(void)playAudio
{

    self.audioController = [[AEAudioController alloc] initWithAudioDescription:[AEAudioController nonInterleaved16BitStereoAudioDescription] inputEnabled:YES];
    _audioController.preferredBufferDuration = 0.005;
    [_audioController start:NULL];

    [self initWithAudioController:self.audioController];

    if ( _player ) {
        [_audioController removeChannels:@[_player]];
        self.player = nil;
    } else {
        NSArray *documentsFolders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [documentsFolders[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFileName];
        if ( ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path] ) return;

        NSError *error = nil;
        self.player = [AEAudioFilePlayer audioFilePlayerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];

        if ( !_player ) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Couldn't start playback: %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] show];
            return;
        }
         [self startTimer];
        _player.removeUponFinish = YES;

        _player.completionBlock = ^{
            _audioController = nil;
            [ _audioController removeChannels:@[_player]];
            [self remveTimer];
            self.player = nil;

        };
        [_audioController addChannels:@[_player]];

    }

}




- (id)initWithAudioController:(AEAudioController*)audioController {

    self.audioController = audioController;
    NSError *error = NULL;
    BOOL result = [self.audioController start:&error];
    if ( !result ) {
        // Report error
        NSLog(@"The Amazing Audio Engine didn't start!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"The Amazing Audio Engine started perfectly!");
    }



    return self;
}
```